# How to autocreate home directories in automounted NFS directory?

Tags: permissions, ldap, nfs, home-directory, autofs

I have a NFS server at `nfs.example.com:/users`. I have a normal server at `client.example.com`. When I do `su - user`, I want it not only to automount `/users/user`, but I also want to create `/users/user` if it is not created already.

If I allows autofs to mount the home directory, I get the response: `Unable to create and initialize directory '/users/user'` after I attempt to su in as an LDAP user. Also, I cannot create any files inside `/users`.

However, if I mount the directory using `mount`, I do not have this permissions issue.

Is autofs mounting the NFS directory differently that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pam module such as pam_mkhomedir. Here's an example: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1411233